# You have your own particular, specific problems — financial, intimate, psychological, and OTHERWISE

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, sentence-meaning

> You have your own particular, specific problems — financial, intimate, psychological, and **otherwise**.

"otherwise" is usually put to make a contract, to show that something is different from what was previously mentioned. In this sentence, though, it looks like it's conveying the meaning of "and so on"/"and so forth"/"and the like".

I've never encountered this usage before. It seems strangely unfamiliar, and it doesn't fit into my understanding of the word.

The quote is from the book *12 Rules for Life: An Antidote to Chaos* by John Peterson. Here is the full context:

> Be cautious when comparing yourself to others. You're a singular being, once you're an adult. You have your own particular, specific problems — financial, intimate, psychological, and otherwise. Those are embedded in the unique broader context of your existence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [The Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/otherwise), in this context applies definition #5:

> otherwise, adj:
>   5. of a different kind.

Consequently, your example sentence would be:

> You have your own particular, specific problems — financial, intimate, psychological, and of a different kind.